# Tomcat-6.0.18, expanded directory structure, datasource in context.xml

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, datasource, jndi

Environment:

- Tomcat-6.0.18
- Oracle-Db
- JDK-1.6.0_1

**-1- *context.xml* i a war file - works fine**

*my-application.war/META-INF/context.xml*:

```
<Resource 
  auth="Container" 
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
  maxActive="5" 
  maxIdle="1" 
  maxWait="-1" 
  name="jdbc/dataource-name" 
  password="pwd" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host-name:1521:xe" 
  username="name"/>
```

Important: *context.xml* is placed in a War-archive in this case. After deploying the application can access the database without problems

**-2- *context.xml* in an expanded directory structure (does not work)**:

*my-application/META-INF/context.xml* (same content)

Important: context.xml is placed in a expanded directory structure in this case. After deployment application con not access the database. Exception message is:
*javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context*

**My question**:

How do i configure tomcat (or my application) in case 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please forget my posting...

Case 2 works fine too!